# no battery indicator in my statue bar and also there is no battery folder

Tags: battery

greetings from China.I am using Hasee K540D i5-D2 which includes

- i5-4210M
- nVidia GT940M/Intel® HD Graphics 4600
- Mobile Intel® HM86 Chipset

I've install elemntary OS freya for a while and everything works fine except the battery indicator.

I installed the same version in my Thinkpad X230 it has the battery indicator,but not my Hasee.

And I cannot use any command line to check the how many battery left as I dont have the battery folder.It just cannot detect my battery.

However it can be charge,I can start up and my Hasee with only battery.I am really confused,are there any solutions?

[image: using my battery]

[image: no battery indicator]